# Index out of bounds when assigning list item by indexer

Tags: c#, arrays, list, serialization

Can anyone explain to me why I get error of index out of bounds in the below code ? please notice I can not specify the size of any array and I need it to be dynamic :

```
        List<int[]> rows = new List<int[]>();
        List<int> FoundAs = new List<int>();
        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                FoundAs.Add(i);
            rows[k] = FoundAs.ToArray(); // Here is the error
            FoundAs.Clear();
        }
```

UPDATE :

The issue is solved , but still I can't access the inner arrays for instance :

```
        int[] temp = new int[rows[y].Length]; // Index out of Bounds
        for (int i=0;i<temp.Length;i++)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
```

Comment: `rows[k]` does not exist; `rows` has 0 elements at that point. What do you expect that to do? You could've found this by introducing a variable: `var foundAsArray = FoundAs.ToArray(); row[k] = foundAsArray;`. Then you'd see which statement exactly caused the exception.

Comment: You need to include the code where `y` is initialized.  My guess is that `y` is at some point outside the bounds of the array...

Comment: y is always less than the size of rows  , but still I cant access the inner array it says index out of bounds

Comment: If you get index out of bounds for that line then either `y < 0` or `y >= rows.Length`.  Just debug it and see what the value of `y` is.

Comment: there is a missing line it should be temp=rows[y]; Thank you

Comment: Read @juharr's comment again. You need to inspect the value of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add to the list because it is currently empty.

```
rows.Add(FoundAs.ToArray());
```

Comment: Inner arrays are not accessible ?